# Rails: Is state machine enough for the approval process?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, state-machine

In our `rails` app, some `model` may require `approval process`. For example, for `purchasing order (PO)`, usually it starts with a submission of the `PO`, then manager approves and CEO approves before the `PO` can be sent out to suppliers. The approval procedure is likely predefined. Along with the `approval process`, we would also like to record data for every transition:

```
  1. who did it (use id), 
  2. when she/he did it (time stamp) 
  3. comment by approval person (usually text). 
  4. approval process can be attached to the model late on demand.
```

There are quite a few `state machine` `ruby gem` out there (such as `state machine`). Our question is that: is the state machine enough to fulfill the requirement laid out above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used [workflow](https://github.com/geekq/workflow) gem to do similar stuff.

It has several states and transition event to switch from one to another state. You can record the data in the transition event.

Comment: Very interesting!  There is a workflow gem called ruote. What's the difference between workflow and ruote?

Comment: Can we specify who can do what in process definition? Who can be a user or a group of users. What is an event which triggers the transition.

Comment: I haven't used ruote before. From their document they claim 'Ruote is oriented towards persistency / modifiability instead of transience / performance like a regular interpreter is', which aim at long-running processes. While workflow is more like finite state machine.

Comment: Yes we can specify it in the transition function. If you look at the document of workflow you will find something like   event :submit, :transitions_to => :awaiting_review,   in the event submit you can specify who did it, when, etc. And submit will be the event to trigger the transition.